# How docker handles container shutdown, when sending shutdown signal to host machine?

Tags: linux, docker, shutdown

**Scenario**
We have a server running Ubuntu Server 16.04 and Docker. Every day, at the end of the day, we have to shut down our servers (Company's policies..) and turn them on again in the next day.

We turn off our server, by sending a shutdown sign to it, remotely (ssh).

**Problem**
I believe that the containers are not being shut down gracefully, because I've noticed that containers such as MySql, sometimes boot up on recovery mode, and we even get some corrupted files as well.

**Question**
How does Docker handle shutdown sign from the host machine? Does it send a stop sign to every container, or does it just kills everything?

And how do we prevent this kind of issue from happening again? Should we make a script to send a docker stop command to all our containers, before we shut down the host machine?

Comment: If this calls `docker stop` then it will only wait 10 seconds (by default) on a SIGTERM before sending a SIGKILL.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add a script that gets executed during shutdown:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
```

You can read more on how to add your command in `/etc/rc0.d/README`